# Get Radio Button value with jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have these radio buttons.

```
<input type="radio" id="flip" name="flip" value="Head" checked="checked" /> Head
<input type="radio" id="flip" name="flip" value="Tail"  /> Tail
```

I am trying to process a form with ajax for which I tried to get the value of these radio buttons with this

```
var dataString = {
    flip: $("#flip").val()
};
console.log(dataString.flip);
```

Now when I do `console.log` to check the value its sending I am always getting `Head` and not Tail even if I select Tail as a choice. Can anyone help me as why is it so?

Comment: you cannot have the same ID multiple times!

Comment: `id="flip"` => `class="flip"` -- `$("#flip")` => `$(".flip")`

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

get value by name not id :

```
$("input[name='flip']:checked").val();
```

Answer (score 2):

`id` cannot be duplicate. It need to be unique.In this case you can use `name` attribute

Use name to select get the selected radio button value

```
$("input:radio[name=flip]:checked").val();
```

Comment: It should be this I guess.. This gave me result not your's.. please check `$("input[name='flip']:checked").val();`

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have the same ID multiple times! that is the reaon why it only displays one of the two.

Comment: then what is the solution to this?

Comment: Use an attribute selector instead `[name="flip"]`.

Answer (score 0):

ID `#flip` is an unique element(you cannot have more than more `#flip` element). Use `.flip` instead of `#flip`.

And also change `id="flip"` to `class="flip"`